# Django DateField not allowing null

Tags: django, forms, date, null, models

A common problem it seems but the remedies suggested in other questions on here don't seem to work for me.

I am submitting some dates via a html form, some are not required and can be blank. However I am getting the error

```
[u'Enter a valid date in YYYY-MM-DD format.']
```

Below is my models file

```
class ProjectM(models.Model):
    order_received = models.DateField(null=True,blank=True)
```

MySQL DB

```
Field                  | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra
order_received         | date         | YES  |     | NULL    |
```

So the way I understand it, I should be setting it to True for null and blank in the models file and make sure in my mysql DB I am allowing NULL. However I still get the validation error mentioned above, when I check the value in the POST data of this particular field, it is ''. I have tried changing the value in the html being generated to check for an empty field and make the value 'null' but this didn't seem to work either.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Update: @Cathy , here is mode code to describe the problem. I omitted some code which is totally irrelevant to the problem and simplified it a bit. Basically I am building a little database web front, it just pulls records out, displays in tabular format in a form and allows you to edit and update the record. It will pull out a blank date field fine, but won't let me update.

Template

```
{% for record in records %}
<form method="post" action="">
<tr>
<td><input type="submit" value="{{ record.id }}" name="submit"></td>
<td><input type="text" value="{{ record.pm }}" name="pm"></td>
<td><input type="text" value="{{ record.spec }}" name="spec"></td>
<td><input type="date" value="{{ record.order_received|date:"Y-m-d" }}" name="order_received"></td>
</tr>
</form>
{% endfor %}
```

Models

```
class ProjectM(models.Model):
    pm = models.CharField(max_length="200")
    spec = models.CharField(max_length="200")
    order_received = models.DateField(null=True,blank=True)
```

View

```
def all(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        id = request.POST['submit']
        pm = request.POST['pm']
        spec = request.POST['spec']
        order_received = request.POST['order_received']
        if not order_received:
            order_received = 'None'
        update = ProjectM.objects.get(pk=int(id))
        update.pm = pm
        update.spec = spec
        update.order_received = order_received
        update.save()
```

Update Template Code

```
{% if record.order_received %}
 <td>
  <div class="styled-dateentered">
   <input class="entered" name='order_received{{ record.id }}' id="order_received{{ record.id }}" type="date" value="{{ record.order_received|date:"Y-m-d" }}">
  </div>
 </td>
{% else %}
 <td>
  <div class="styled-datenotentered">
   <input class="notentered" id="order_received{{ record.id }}" name="order_received{{ record.id }}" type="date" value="None">
  </div>
 </td>
{% endif %}
```

I hope this helps. I really appreciate the help.

Thanks

Comment: put "required=False" in that field

Comment: what does your form look like

Comment: my form is pretty basic, lets just say something like this <form method="post" action=""><input type="submit"><input type="date" id="order_received" name="order_received" value="{{ record.order_receiveded|date:"Y-m-d" }}"> , it pulls out a date from the DB and displays it, if there is one. Otherwise it displays dd/mm/yyyy but the value is set to ''. If I select a date and update it works, but if I update leaving the field blank I get the error.

Comment: @cathy I am not using the model.forms in django to create my forms. I tried this inside my field options in the models file but it spat an error im guessing because its not really a mysql field option.

Comment: May I see your complete codes? Just update your question

Comment: try deleting your database and sync again. Look in your database if your date is allow the null and blank value

Comment: Sometimes Django not allow to update the model if that model has already been use before you put blank and null function.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a `ModelForm` wich represents this model `ProjectM`, for example:

```
class ProjectMForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ProjectM
```

you shouldn't have any problem, but be sure you don't have a field in this form called `order_received`, without a `required=False` param in this `form`. If you want to have a field with this name you should do this: `order_received = forms.DateField(required=False)`

Comment: thankyou for your response. I'm not actually using the built django forms to create my form so I have no ModelForm information. Im passing the data to my view via POST. When i look in the traceback the POST['order_received'] is indeed empty. Does it need to be the value NULL or just an empty string? Thanks again

Comment: I dropped my database and resync'ed my DB with Django and still seem to be experiencing the problems. Is there a way I can simply turn off form validation in Django? I don't really need it to be honest.

Comment: I noticed that you are using `POST` method and you don't have `{% csrf_token %}` in your form.

Comment: Well, I have tested deeply your code. You can solve the problem giving `None` to `order_received` field when it comes empty. For example: `update.order_received = order_received if order_received else None`, because as you mentioned, the empty string is not recognized as a valid value to `Date` data type.

Comment: @ Vladir i have the csrf exempt code in my view as I was having troubles with it. I will give your method a go, i had a feeling it was something like that, like an empty string is indeed not 'null' or 'none'. Lets see how that goes.

Comment: @ Vladir. I tried what you said, perhaps I am not doing it correctly because it still doesn't seem to work for me. In my template code I have tried setting the value of the date field to 'None' where there is is no value coming from the database. I have added this to my original post. The problem is, when I look in the traceback , the value 'None' is still not assigned to my order_received post variable, even though when I search through the page's source code, the value of none is definitely set. I have updated the code i placed in my view too, perhaps i am doing it in the wrong way.

Comment: Ahhh in `order_received = 'None'`, the `None` value without the quotes, only `order_received = None`. Check again and let me know if it works now.

Comment: Vladir - setting to None instead of 'None' seems to work, pretty stoked!! I really appreciate your assistance on this matter.